# entire function with $f(n) = f'(n)$ for every integer $n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there exists an entire function $f$ such that $f(n) = f'(n)$ for every integer $n$, and such that the range of $f$ includes both $0$ and $1$.

I have tried quite a few different things but did not make any significant progress. Assuming the converse and trying to reach a contradiction did not work. Also using Weierstrass factorization theorem for the entire function $f(z)-f'(z)$ with zeroes at the integers did not get me anywhere as well. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$f(z) = \exp(z) \cdot \cos(2\pi \cdot z).$$

Then

$$f'(z) = \exp(z) \cdot \cos(2\pi \cdot z)- 2\pi \cdot \exp(z) \cdot \sin (2\pi \cdot z)$$

In particular,

$$f'(z) = \exp(z) \cdot \cos(2\pi \cdot z)$$

for any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, $f(0)=1$, $f(1/4)=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(z)=\sin(\pi z)+\pi \cos(\pi z)$.  Then $f'(z) = \pi \cos(\pi z) - \pi^2 \sin(\pi z)$.  So $f(n) = \pi (-1)^n = f'(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Since $f$ can also be expressed as a single $\cos$ form it takes all complex values.